# Gwt Super Dev Mode on IE8 - "Dev Mode On button

Tags: gwt

I am trying to use the super dev mode on IE8,
I cant understand how to add the "Dev Mode On" button,
I tried to import from chrome but it failed.

maybe its working differently on IE?

Answer (score 1):

What version of GWT are you using ?
Those buttons aren't needed anymore since a pretty long time (something like 2 years).

Comment: I am using GWT 2.3, I know its an old version, but I need to stay with this version for now

Comment: Impossible. SDM was introduced in 2.5.